# How to use a variable in a filter parameter?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to pull some properties from the bitlocker active directory object, which I can do just fine using PowerShell and typing all the info in. for  example

```
Get-ADObject -filter 'CN -like "*A3F850A4*"' `
             -Properties CanonicalName,msFVE-RecoveryPassword
```

Works just fine to pull the properties, but I can't figure out how to use a variable in -filter parameter and get it to return any info, this is the code I have tried.

```
[string]$passwordId = Read-Host `
                  "What is the first 8 charcters of the recovery password id?"
Get-ADObject -filter {CN -like $passwordId} ` 
             -Properties CanonicalName,msFVE-RecoveryPassword
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially any info on using variables in scripts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AD cmdlets filters don't really act as usual PowerShell syntax.

I would suggest using `-LdapFilter` instead (it's more portable to other tools, and most often don't differ so much from PowerShell-ish filters):

```
Get-ADObject -LdapFilter "(cn=*$passwordId*)"
```

In case you insist on using -Filter: just make sure that you will get correct string first:

```
$likePattern = "*$passwordId*"
Get-ADObject -Filter {cn -like $likePattern}
```

Or use string notation (with some extra quotes) instead:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter "cn -like '*$passwordId*'"
```

But again: these filters won't work outside MS AD module, LDAP filter can be used in every tool I've seen for searching AD (including ADSISearcher and Quest cmdlets for AD).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this still doesn't work with "-LDAPFilter '(anr=variable)':

```
$user = Read-Host -Prompt "What user or email?
Get-ADUser -LdapFilter '(anr=$user)' -Properties * |Select SamAccountName, Mail, CanonicalName
```